# Oracle losing connection ( ORA-03114 ) after some time not using the software

Tags: oracle

After some time idle, if users try to use the our system, we receive the error:

`ORA-03114 - not connected to Oracle`.

I know there's a parameter called SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME.

the recomendation is `SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=10` but I didn't find what this 10 means.

I'm a SQL Server DBA trying to help our Oracle senior dba.

Our sqlnet.ora file is like this:

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

Shoud I add `**SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=10**` on it?

To simulate the error, if we open the software and leave it idle for 1hr, we receive the error.

IDLE_TIME is unlimited too on dba_profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work. The `10` is a value in minutes ([documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF209)).

> To specify a time interval, in minutes, to send a check to verify that
>   client/server connections are active

The official Oracle documentation regarding DCD (Dead Connection Detection) is [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/oraclenetdcd-2179641.pdf).

The primary purpose of `SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=10` is to clean up dead connections, but (I quote):

> A less common usage scenario for DCD is to keep database connections
>   alive when an external firewall timeout is configured to terminate
>   idle connections